# Приложение с OSMDroid компилируется, но не запускается на устройстве

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Создаю приложение в AndroidStudio 3.0.1. с использованием OSMDroid оффлайн карты.
Подключаю библиотеки: osmdroid-android-4.0.jar,  osmdroid-android-4.0-javadoc.jar, osmdroid-packager-4.0.jar и slf4j-android-1.5.8-sources.jar. В проекте в ProjctStructure - Dependencies добавил.

В манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

В разметке простой код:

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Compil SDK Version = API:28
Build Tool Version = 28.0.3
Min SDK и Target SDK Version = API:19
```

В MainActivity код, тоже по примеру

```
import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  MapView map = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
 map.setUseDataConnection(false);
 map.setMaxZoomLevel(19);
 map.setMinZoomLevel(14);
 map.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
 map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
 final GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(47.990554, 37.800179);
 final IMapController MC = map.getController();
 MC.setCenter(startPoint);
 MC.setZoom(19);
 map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("xUSSR.Roads.Visicom 2.0",null, 14, 19, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {}));
 map.setClickable(true);
 }
 }
```

В BildGrable(Project.Test) добавил

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()    //add this if it's missing
}
}
```

Приложение компилируется без ошибок, на реальном устройстве (Android 7.0) устанавливается, но не запускается. Что я делаю не так или что не доделал?

Comment: Что значит не запускается? Крашится при запуске? Если да, то приложите логи краша.

Comment: Пишет "В приложении произошла ошибка. Перезапустить", при перезапуске тоже самое, только "Закрыть". А где логи поглядеть? Я встраивать ведение логов в приложение не умею(

Comment: У вас таки да, какая-то ошибка. Если вы запускаете из AndroidStudio приложение - смотрите там во вкладке logCat логи. Там и будет ошибка.

Comment: logCat ругается на adb, а в EventLog получаю      23:42 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

23:43 Unable to detect adb version, adb output: 

23:47 Gradle build finished in 5m 8s 259ms

Comment: Очень странно... Может быть стоит попробовать переустановить студию и/или AndroidSdk. Без логов нельзя сказать в чём у вас проблема.

Comment: Может ноут сильно старый? Asus X50V. Спасибо, завтра попробую переустановиться.

Comment: Не думаю, что ноут тут может сыграть роль. ADB - очень маленькая консольная программа, вообще ничего по мощности требовать не должна.

Comment: Установил недостающие dll-ки, ADB запускается, но в Log Cat все равно не работает, даже переустановки PlatformTools

Comment: Тогда всё плохо... Без логов ничего сделать нельзя( Попробуйте на другом компе студию поставить и там приложение запустить.

Comment: Для корректной работы adb требуется Visual C++ 2015, при установке/переустановке С++ на обработке файла windows7_MSU_x64 возникает ошибка 0x80240017, гугл-поиск горит, что у многих такая болезнь, нужно обновление KB2999226, которое тоже не хочет ставиться. Буду компилировать на другой машине, когда все закончу. Всем спасибо за помощь!